# C# , User is Authorized while Membership.GetUser() is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

How this is possible, a user is Authenticated while `Membership.GetUser() ==  null` ?

```
[Authorize]
public class UserController : Controller
{    
     public ActionResult DoSomething()
     {
        var user =  Membership.GetUser();    // user can access here and be null

     }
}
```

[Link to Web.confing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAffv.jpg)

Comment: It seems that you have ASP.Net Membership and other *(might be ASP.Net Identity)*? Could you check what kind of membership you have in your application?

Comment: I was using this code to generate SQL tables:   C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<versionNumber>\aspnet_regsql.exe

Comment: How do you login user? Could you also show web.config?

Comment: I am using Forms Authentication. I've uploaded a link to the  web.config image

Comment: Could you post to code of **login action method** and **CustomizedRoleProvider**?